# PHP action form is not sending e-mails

Tags: php, html, forms, email

everyone, I know this might have been asked a 1000 times, but I'm not familiar with PHP, and I cannot find the error to my file. I have made this simple contact form on HTML.

```
<form action="form_gm4.php" method="post" name="contact_form" id="contactForm" >


                <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <label>Qual o seu perfil?</label><br />
                <label><input type="radio" name="perfil" value="Médico">Médico</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="perfil" value="Paciente">Paciente</label>
                <p class="help-block"></p>                  
                </div>
                </div>


                <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <label>Nome do Paciente:</label>
                <input name="nome" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Preenchimento obrigatório')"    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <label>Nome do médico:</label>
                <input name="nomenedico" type="text" class="form-control" id="namemedico" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Preenchimento obrigatório')"    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <label>Telefone residencial - (DDD) + número:</label>
                <input name="telefone" type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Preenchimento obrigatório')"    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <label>Telefone celular - (DDD) + número:</label>
                <input name="celular" type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Preenchimento obrigatório')"    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <label>Medicamento prescrito:</label>
                <input name="medicamento" type="text" class="form-control" id="medicamento" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Preenchimento obrigatório')"    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <label>Patologia:</label>
                <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="ArtritePsoriasica" type="checkbox" value="on">Artrite psoriásica</label></div>
                <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="AsmaGrave" type="checkbox" value="on">Asma grave</label></div>
                <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="CAPS" type="checkbox" value="on">CAPS</label></div>
                <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="EspondiliteAnquilosante" type="checkbox" value="on">Espondilite anquilosante</label></div>
                <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="Osteoporose" type="checkbox" value="on">Osteoporose</label></div>
                <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="Psoriase" type="checkbox" value="on">Psoríase</label></div>
                <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="Urticaria" type="checkbox" value="on">Urticária</label></div>
                <p class="help-block"></p>                  
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <label>CRM do médico:</label>
                <input name="CRM" type="text" class="form-control" id="CRM" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Preenchimento obrigatório')"    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <label>UF do médico:</label>
                <input name="UF" type="text" class="form-control" id="UF" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Preenchimento obrigatório')"    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
                </div>


                <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <label>Termos de uso:</label>
                <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="regulamento" required onchange="this.setCustomValidity(validity.valueMissing ? 'Por favor, leia e aceite o regulamento do programa!' : '');" >Leia e aceite o <a href="regulamento_do_programa_bem_estar_respiratorio.pdf" target="_blank">regulamento do programa</a>.</label></div>
                <p class="help-block"></p>                  
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <label>Declaração:</label>
                <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="declaracao" required onchange="this.setCustomValidity(validity.valueMissing ? 'Por favor, leia e aceite o regulamento do programa!' : '');" >Declaro que o paciente foi corretamente orientado sobre o Programa Bem Estar da Novartis, e concorda em participar e compartilhar as informações pessoais com o médico abaixo fornecidas, autorizando o contato via telefone para confirmação de dados cadastrais, bem como o envio de materiais informativos e de apoio via correio no endereço fornecido.</label></div>
                <p class="help-block"></p>                  
                </div>
                </div>


                <button name="Enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-default" >Enviar</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-default"  name="Apagar" type="reset" value="Apagar">Apagar</button>



                </form>
```

But the PHP is not sending it as expected, can you guys please help me tell what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the PHP

```
<?php

$perfil = $_POST['perfil'] = ( isset($_POST['perfil']) ) ? $_POST['perfil'] : null;
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$nomenedico = $_POST['nomenedico'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$celular = $_POST['celular'];
$medicamento = $_POST['medicamento'];
$ArtritePsoriasica = $_POST['ArtritePsoriasica'] = ( isset($_POST['ArtritePsoriasica']) ) ? true : null;
$AsmaGrave = $_POST['AsmaGrave']  = ( isset($_POST['AsmaGrave']) )  ? true : null;
$CAPS = $_POST['CAPS'] = ( isset($_POST['CAPS']) ) ? true : null;
$EspondiliteAnquilosante = $_POST['EspondiliteAnquilosante']  = ( isset($_POST['EspondiliteAnquilosante']) )  ? true : null;
$Osteoporose = $_POST['Osteoporose'] = ( isset($_POST['Osteoporose']) ) ? true : null;
$Psoriase = $_POST['Psoriase']  = ( isset($_POST['Psoriase']) )  ? true : null;
$Urticaria = $_POST['Urticaria']  = ( isset($_POST['Urticaria']) )  ? true : null;
$CRM = $_POST['CRM'];
$UF = $_POST['UF'];
$regulamento = $_POST['regulamento'] = ( isset($_POST['regulamento']) ) ? $_POST['regulamento'] : null;
$declaracao = $_POST['declaracao'] = ( isset($_POST['declaracao']) ) ? $_POST['declaracao'] : null;



$to = "andressa.casale@gmail.com";
$subject = "Cadastro no Bem Estar";

$msg2 = "<strong>Perfil: </strong> $perfil =\n";
$msg2 .= "<br> <strong>Nome do paciente:</strong> $nome\n";
$msg2 .= "<br>  <strong>Nome do médico: </strong> $nomenedico\n";
$msg2 .= "<br>  <strong>Telefone: </strong> $telefone\n";
$msg2 .= "<br>  <strong>Celular: </strong> $celular\n";
$msg2 .= "<br>  <strong>Medicamento: </strong> $medicamento\n";
$msg2 .= "<br>  <strong>Patologia: </strong> $ArtritePsoriasica\n $AsmaGrave\n $CAPS\n $EspondiliteAnquilosante\n $Osteoporose\n $Psoriase\n $Urticaria\n";
$msg2 .= "<br>  <strong>CRM do médico: </strong> $CRM\n";
$msg2 .= "<br>  <strong>UF do médico: </strong> $UF\n";
$msg2 .= "<br>  <strong>Regulamento: </strong> $regulamento\n";
$msg2 .= "<br>  <strong>Declaração: </strong> $declaracao\n";



mail ($to, $subject, $msg2);

echo ("Seu cadastro foi enviado com sucesso! <a href='respiratorio.html'>Voltar</a>");



?>
```

Comment: Hi @John Conde, my form is different from the one on the question you marked as duplicated, I really need help. I looked everywhere in this forum and could not fix my problem.

Comment: So its not sending at all? I think you need to add headers

Comment: also $mensagem isn't doing anything, if you want those at the bottom of the email you need them to be $msg2

Comment: How do I set up headers? Og those $mesagem tags were not supposed to be there I'll edit it out.

Comment: Just put this code after the $msg2 variables replacing "info@example.com" with your email address: $headers = 'From: info@example.com' . "\n" .
    'Reply-To: info@example.com' . "\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";

mail($to, $subject, $msg2, $headers);